# Creating a variable that stores an array of resolved promises?

Tags: javascript, express, spotify

I feel like I'm digging myself into a hole here. I have an array of artists names and using Spotify's API I wanted to grab the top tracks of each artist and pass that to my view page. So with Spotify's API, I could search for an artists name, but in order to grab each of their top tracks, I need their ID as well. I have written this:

```
      PromiseArr = [];
      // Search with Spotify's API for each artist from the list of concerts retrieved
      for (var i = 0; i < concerts.length; i++) {

     // Create an array of unresloved promises and resolve all of them afterwards with Promise.all 

        PromiseArr.push(spotifyApi.searchArtists(concerts[i].performance[0].displayName));
      }

      let artists = [];
      artists = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.all(PromiseArr)
          .then(values => {

            // Retrieve the Artist ID in order to make calls for specific track's
            const artistIds = values.map(element => {
              if (element.body.artists.items[0]) {
                return element.body.artists.items[0].id;
              }
            });
            resolve(artistIds);
          })
          .catch(err => reject(err));
      });
      artists.then(value => res.json(value.filter(element => element != null)));
```

So this gives me an array of all the artists codes:

```
[
  "391oLRVmoTkumiN79HkTWu",
  "066X20Nz7iquqkkCW6Jxy6",
  "3ur7kjN4pd94zjUxrFSMDj",
  "26AHtbjWKiwYzsoGoUZq53",
  "3P33qFNGBVXl86yQYWspFj",
  "3bFSIkxpW9NvKT1wzo9tgx",
  "4MOSNls51nJPFORKok60vV",
  "50JJSqHUf2RQ9xsHs0KMHg",
  "6reL7Hq6obyCxSqurc8i1D",
  "0I7U5I66P88nCaVVPkIz6x",
]
```

From there, I'd be able to loop through the values and make an API call to retrieve the top tracks for each artist. However, I feel like what I'm doing is very redundant. And I can't seem to store the Artists' ID's into a variable and loop through those. i.e.

```
const IDs = artists.then(value => res.json(value.filter(element => element != null)));
```

`IDs` would be empty. How exactly can I go on about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform that array of artist codes into an array of promises. Then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to detect when all the promises in the array have been fulfilled.

For example.

Get the array of artist codes:

```
var array = [
  "391oLRVmoTkumiN79HkTWu",
  "066X20Nz7iquqkkCW6Jxy6",
  "3ur7kjN4pd94zjUxrFSMDj",
  "26AHtbjWKiwYzsoGoUZq53",
  "3P33qFNGBVXl86yQYWspFj",
  "3bFSIkxpW9NvKT1wzo9tgx",
  "4MOSNls51nJPFORKok60vV",
  "50JJSqHUf2RQ9xsHs0KMHg",
  "6reL7Hq6obyCxSqurc8i1D",
  "0I7U5I66P88nCaVVPkIz6x",
];
```

Create a new array of promises (instead of strings) using `Array.map` based on the codes from the first array.

```
var promiseArray = array.map(function(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //do API call here
        //item will be the string of the artist code
        //call the resolve function when complete with the API call
    });
});
```

Then you can use `Promise.all` to detect when all promises in the `promiseArray` have been resolved or when the first one fails (if there is a failure).

```
Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(results) {
    //do stuff here
}).catch(function(error) {
    //handle error here
});
```